# SwiftUI having a problem when I want to update a value in an array with a foreach

Tags: arrays, swiftui, foreach

I'm trying to modify a value in an array in a forEach but I've got this error : `Cannot assign to property: 'place' is a 'let' constant` and I don't know why. My array is all defined by `var` and not by `let`...

My structure definition :

```
struct Place: Identifiable{
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    var lat: Double
    var long: Double
    var Name: String
    var proximity: Double
    
    init (lat: Double, long: Double, Name: String, proximity: Double){
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long
        self.Name = Name
        self.proximity = proximity
    }
    
    init(config: NewPlaceConfig){
        self.lat = config.lat
        self.long = config.long
        self.Name = config.Name
        self.proximity = config.proximity
    }
}
```

My NewPlaceConfig definition :

```
struct NewPlaceConfig{
    var lat: Double
    var long: Double
    var Name: String
    var proximity: Double
}
```

My Data definition :

```
class PlaceLibrary: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var testPlace = [
        Place(lat: 46.1810, long: 6.2304, Name: "Text1", proximity: 0.0),
        Place(lat: 46.1531, long: 6.2951, Name: "Text2", proximity: 0.0),
        Place(lat: 46.1207, long: 6.3302, Name: "Text3", proximity: 0.0)
    ]
}
```

And finally my code where I've got the problem :

```
[...]
@ObservedObject var placeLibrary: PlaceLibrary
[...]
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        lastLocation = location
        
        ForEach(placeLibrary.testPlace){place in
            let currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: (self.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude) ?? 0.0, longitude: (self.lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude) ?? 0.0)
            let comparedLocation = CLLocation(latitude: place.lat, longitude: place.long)
            place.proximity = currentLocation.distance(from: comparedLocation) //HERE IS THE LINE WITH THE PROBLEM
            
        }

    }
```

In fact I just want to compare the curent user Position to the one save in each places in my array and then add in my array the current distance between the user and the saved place. I'd like to add update this value in the `proximity` box of my array that's why I write this line :

```
place.proximity = currentLocation.distance(from: comparedLocation)
```

But without any success and I don't find why ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `ForEach` is for use inside a `View` hierarchy. You're probably looking for `placeLibrary.testPlace.forEach { `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bit of a mixup between SwiftUI and Swift in your code.

- `ObservableObject` and the related `@ObservedObject` property wrapper is used in SwiftUI views to preserve state and update the view whenever a published property of the observed object is changed.
- your function `locationManager` is a regular Swift function. It does not return a view.
- `ForEach` is a SwiftUI function that returns a view.

So it's hard to answer this question without a better picture of your code.

Generally speaking, however, any foreach-like construct (either the `ForEach` SwiftUI view that you're using, a `.forEach { }` method called on an array, or the classic `for x in list { }` syntax) all give you a **copy** of the element in the array you're traversing, not the actual element. And yes, these copies that `forEach` hands you are read-only - let - constants.

When you're looping over an array of classes, this doesn't matter. Classes are a [reference type](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10), so the 'copy' that you get in each foreach-loop is a reference to the actual element in the traversed array.

Structs, however, are value types. The 'copy' that a foreach-loop gives you, is a physically different variable than the element in the array. Even if you *were* able to mutate it, the actual element in the actual array you're looping over wouldn't be updated.

If you need to iterate over an array of structs and update (some of) its elements, your best bet is to iterate over the array's indices instead, then access the actual element you want to update through the array's subscript:

```
for idx in placeLibary.testPlace.indices { 
    // Calculate stuff
    // ...

    // Update the array
    placeLibrary.testPlace[idx].proximity = newProximity
}
```

If you also need to read properties of the actual element (for example to calculate the `comparedLocation` variable in your example), you can use `enumerated()`, which hands you both the index and the element. However, never forget to update the actual list, not the (read-only) element!

```
for (idx, readOnlyPlace) in placeLibary.testPlace.enumerated() {
    // Calculate stuff
    let currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: (self.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude) ?? 0.0, longitude: (self.lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude) ?? 0.0)
    let comparedLocation = CLLocation(latitude: readOnlyPlace.lat, longitude: readOnlyPlace.long)

    // Update the array
    placeLibrary.testPlace[idx].proximity = currentLocation.distance(from: comparedLocation)
}
```

Comment: Oh okay I see my mistake ! Reading your last exemple of code seem to answer my question ! I just begin with SwiftUI so I'm a little bit lost between Swift and Swift UI !! I'll try this code asap !

Comment: No worries, it confused me too when I was starting out  Don’t forget to mark the question as answered btw